# É necessário usar o subjuntivo ou o indicativo com frases como "É possível pensar que" ou "É natural supor que"?

Tags: português-brasileiro, gramática, modo-subjuntivo

Devemos usar o subjuntivo ou o indicativo em frases como "É possível pensar que" ou "É natural supor que"?  Existe uma regra geral para isso, ou depende da implicação?

O que me faz pensar nisso é que eu estava conversando com um amigo sobre "notícias falsas".  Falei alguma coisa assim, mas fiquei em dúvida se seria melhor usar "seja" ou "é":

> "Quando um amigo seu compartilha uma notícia, é natural supor que seja verdade.  No entanto, hoje em dia... "

E agora, estou pensando em geral nas frases assim que indicam que é possível pensar numa coisa.  Importa se a implicação é que esse pensamento pode ou não estar correto?

Por exemplo:

> "Parece verdade que [algo] está/esteja acontecendo, mas não é assim."
>
> "Parece verdade que [algo] é/seja correto, por causa das evidencias múltiplas."

Essa diferença de implicação (a diferença entre o que é subentendido) afeta o uso do subjuntivo?

Mais um exemplo:

> "Se jogarmos um dado 20 vezes e obtivermos um número baixo, é intuitivo que *seja / é* mais provável que ganhemos um número maior depois.  Mas esse raciocínio é errado"

vs

> "É intuitivo que o gasto público em saúde básica também *melhora / melhore* os resultados educacionais"

A primeira frase quer dizer que realmente não é mas provável, mas no segundo quer dizer que, sim, melhora.  Por isso acho que eu usaria subjuntivo na primeira e indicativo na segunda, mas não sei se estiver certo.

---

#### In English

Generally, it seems to me that subjunctive, as an overarching principle, is used in situations of doubt, or hypotheticals.  Generally it's used to refer to things that *might* or *could* exist, but they ain't necessarily so.

So when saying "Eu não acho que ele saiba" we use the subjunctive, because "him knowing" is doubtful, but "Eu acho que ele sabe" isn't, so we don't. (This distinction is difficult to outline exactly, but this is my experience so far).

My question relates to a situation where you are saying "you could think that" or "it's natural to suppose that".  Is there a general rule for this situation (always use subjunctive, never use subjunctive), or would it depend on the subtext?

If I'm saying

> "it seems true that.."

Would I follow that with a subjunctive? Does that depend on whether I'm saying *"it (falsely) seems true that..."* or *"it seems true that [something], and for good reason"*

An example:

> "It's intuitive to think that if you roll a dice and get a low number 20 times, it's *(seja)* more likely that you'll get a higher number afterwards, but that intuition is wrong"

vs

> "If you stop for a moment, it's intuitive to think that public spending on basic healthcare improves *(melhora)* overall educational achievement too" (here I'm implying that this is true)

I've put my intuition as to how this would work in Portuguese in brackets, my guess is that the implication regarding the veracity of the thought would affect whether to use subjunctive or indicative, but I'm unsure.

Comment: Some Guy,   I can't understand your question.  Feel free to add an English translation. We can all understand it and maybe I will get what you mean.

Comment: @Centaurus that was the politest way to say I'm talking a load of s**t I've ever heard.  I'll read through it again and try and fix it up to a level of comprehensibility, and failing that, write a translation too.  Thanks :)

Comment: Some Guy, I think I understand what you mean.  I suggest the following edit:   Nas frases abaixo, devo usar o presente do indicativo ou o presente do subjuntivo?     - É provável que tudo isso _______ acontecendo (está/esteja)  Já a frase ""Quando um amigo seu compartilha uma notícia, é natural supor que seja verdade. No entanto, hoje em dia... " está gramaticalmente correta?   Suponho que suas dúvidas sejam essas.     Quanto a pergunta "Essa diferença do insinuação afeta a gramática, ou não?" eu não consegui entender.

Comment: "Modo subjuntivo é o modo verbal que não expressa certeza, e sim uma dúvida ou tese", ou seja, a coisa de que se fala não tem de ser falsa. E muito menos o subjuntivo sugere que seja falsa. "Presente: indica uma possibilidade, um fato incerto no presente: **Que**...; Pretérito imperfeito: indica a possibilidade de um fato ter acontecido ou não: **Se**...; Futuro: indica a possibilidade de um fato acontecer: **Quando**
"

Comment: @Centaurus  my original question was all over the place. I'm sure my updated version is still full of errors, but I've tried to be as clear as possible.  I always find your (and others) edits to my attempts to construct my questions in Portuguese really helpful to my development, so I've tried again in portuguese.  However, I've also included an English version in case it's still completely unclear.  Many thanks!

Comment: Some Guy,  O uso do subjuntivo em português é bem diferente do uso do "subjunctive" da língua inglesa. Em português, o uso está mais relacionado ao tipo de oração que contem o verbo.  Sendo uma oração subordinada, usamos o subjuntivo.  Usamos também formas iguais às do subjuntivo em orações principais e em orações coordenadas mas nesses casos não se trata exatamente do subjuntivo e sim de formas do optativo.  Mas não é só isso, e meu conhecimento sobre o assunto não é suficiente para que eu elabore uma boa resposta.

Comment: @Some_Guy "sentenças" are (courtroom) verdicts. Sentences are "frases".

Comment: Why would anyone even mention the subjunctive in English (which really isn't a subjunctive anyway) and its use in Portuguese?

Answer (score 6):

Esta questão é complexa, mas depois de rever mentalmente muitas frases, há uma coisa que é clara: a escolha entre o indicativo e o subjuntivo não depende do pensamento ser correto ou não. Comecemos com frases simples para maior clareza:

> Parece que **está** a chover, mas não está; é ilusão de ótica.
>
> Pensas que o João **foi** à pesca, mas não; ele está é com a outra.

Aqui usamos o indicativo para introduzir uma ideia falsa. E também é possível usar o subjuntivo com ideias certas:

> A Maria está zangada contigo, e é natural que **esteja**; depois do que tu lhe fizeste…

O que acontece é que *parece que* pede o indicativo, mesmo que a “parecença” seja ilusória, e *é natural que* pede o subjuntivo, mesmo que introduza um facto e não apenas uma possibilidade. Agora há expressões que podem vir seguidas do indicativo ou subjuntivo. Neste caso o subjuntivo indica menor convicção:

> (a) Penso que o João **está** em casa.
>
> (b) Penso que o João **esteja** em casa.

Em qualquer das frases, *penso* indica que eu não tenho a certeza; mas (b), com o subjuntivo, dá ideia de uma incerteza maior. O mesmo se aplica ao teu primeiro exemplo, “supor que é/seja verdade”: é possível usar os dois, mas o indicativo indica maior confiança.

Estas regras em princípio mantêm-se em frases mais elaboradas do tipo das tuas, isto é, quando se diz que alguém **pode pensar**, não simplesmente que alguém **pensa**:

> (c) Podemos pensar que o problema **está** resolvido, mas não está.
>
> (d) É natural pensar-se que o sol **é** eterno, mas não é: vai extinguir-se dentro de cinco bilhões de anos.

Aqui poderíamos também usar o subjuntivo em vez do indicativo, indicando menor convicção no pensamento, ou seja:

> *Podemos pensar que o problema **está** resolvido* ≈ *podemos estar convencidos que o problema está resolvido*
>
> *Podemos pensar que o problema **esteja** resolvido* ≈ *podemos pensar que há uma boa probabilidade de o problema estar resolvido*

Agora, se a seguir se vai dizer que essa ideia, apesar de natural, está errada, fazer uma distinção entre estar-se mais ou menos convencido poderá não ser muito importante, e eu não tenho a certeza que as pessoas façam sempre essa distinção, especialmente em frases mais longas e complexas, como por exemplo nesta versão da tua, em que provavelmente as pessoas vão entender a mesma coisa quer uses o indicativo ou o subjuntivo:

> Se jogarmos dado vinte vezes e obtivermos sempre um número baixo, é natural pensar-se que no lançamento seguinte a probabilidade de um numero alto **é/seja**maior, mas…

No teu último exemplo, eu faço a mesma distinção. Com o indicativo *melhora*, é como se afirmasses “é claro que os gastos em saúde **melhoram** os resultados educacionais”; como o subjuntivo *melhore* é mais como “é bem possível que os gastos em saúde **melhorem** os resultados educacionais”.

Comment: Certíssimo como sempre, mas vale a pena ver o negativo, ficaria: Não penso que ele chegue hoje. Ou no interrogativo: Vocês pensam que ele chegue hoje? Nesses casos, precisa ser subjuntivo......né?

Comment: @Lambie, Eu diria que não, que o correto é `Vocês pensam que ele chega hoje?`

Comment: @Lambie, sim no negativo é "não penso que ele chega"; mas no interrogativo, pelo menos aqui em Portugal, é possível ouvir os dois. Com o  indicativo, "pensam que ele chega hoje?", é neutro; "pensam que ele chegue hoje?" indica dúvida. Mais comum em frases como "acham que eu lá vá?" (eu não sei se devo ir ou não).