# Presente do indicativo ou do subjuntivo?

Tags: verbos, conjugações, interpretação

Eu e várias pessoas que conheço recorrentemente ficamos em dúvida de qual usar e porquê. Na frase "Acho que ela está bem", fico na dúvida se não deveria ser "Acho que ela esteja bem"; ambas me parecem certas e com idéias diferentes, mas não consigo ver a diferença. Perguntei a minha mãe, meu avô, minha professora de inglês e até ao meu papagaio, mas ninguém soube me reponder.
Por isso eu vos peço que faleis a diferença que vós vedes ou se um de vós souber a diferença e souber explicar, agradeço der uma resposta. Deixarei alguns exemplos abaixo para vós poderdes opinar sobre, se quiserdes; eu acho que alguns estão errados, mas, vale a pena perguntar.

"Eu acho que ele está/esteja bem"; (não sei)

"Eu espero que ele morre/morra logo!"; (acho que só "morra" está certo)

"Deves namorar com que amas/ames"; (não tenho idéia)

"Eu Queres que eu apague/apago a luz?"; (acho que só "apague" está certo)

"Eu chuto que esta é/seja a resposta certa"; (0 idéias)

"Não há quem realmente chora/chore". (sei menos ainda)

Obrigado de antemão por teres visto! E obrigado se repondeste a minha dúvida; se não, tudo bem também (rimou!)!

Comment: Fico chocado que o papagaio não saiba uma coisa dessas! A esta hora já tou mais a dormir que acordado, mas talvez encontres alguma coisa de útil [nesta questão](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/4097/%c3%89-necess%c3%a1rio-usar-o-subjuntivo-ou-o-indicativo-com-frases-como-%c3%89-poss%c3%advel-pensa/4141#4141)

Comment: Bem me parecia que havia [outra pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/5598/modo-de-verbos-em-cl%c3%a1usulas-com-o-verbo-imaginar-no-afirmativo/5605#5605) sobre este assunto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se o verbo tem a ideia de hipótese, deve-se usar o subjuntivo. Mas se o verbo tem a ideia de uma ação concreta no presente deve-se usar o indicativo:

- "Eu acho que ele está bem" >= concreto
- "Eu espero que ele esteja bem" <= hipotético
- "Eu espero que ele morra logo!" <= hipotético
- "Deves namorar com que amas" <= concreto
- "Queres que eu apague a luz?" <= hipotético
- "Eu chuto que esta seja a resposta certa" <= hipotético
- "Não há quem realmente chora/chore". <= depende do contexto