# “Não se se vá” ou “não sei se vou”?

Tags: modo-subjuntivo

Qual o modo verbal correto do verbo *ir* nas frases a seguir?

“não sei se vá a Portugal” ou “não sei se vou a Portugal”?

Answer (score 2):

Ambas, mas *não sei se vá a Portugal* é usada com o significado *não sei se hei de ir a Portugal* ou *não sei se deva ir a Portugal* (ainda não decidi), por oposição a não conhecer os planos, ou depender apenas de algum fator externo.

[Nesta tese](https://www.maxwell.vrac.puc-rio.br/9025/9025_7.PDF) cujo autor não consegui identificar, cita-se no mesmo sentido Maria Henriqueta  Campos<sup>1</sup>:

> [A] autora mostra que em (33a.) a escolha de um dos valores não depende necessariamente do sujeito S (sujeito sintático de não saber) e sim de fatores externos. Já em (33b.), a escolha para
> validar <eu ir à praia> depende inteiramente da decisão de S. Ou ainda, nestes exemplos, não saber em (33a.) significa “não ter conhecimento”, em (33a.), “(ainda) não ter decidido”:
>
> (33). Não sei se F (Indicativo / Conjuntivo)
> a. não sei se vou à praia.
> b. não sei se vá à praia.

Sobre o Brasil, o mesmo autor diz:

> Vale registrar que, ao contrário do acima mostrado, no Português
> Europeu, não há similaridades no Português do Brasil. Ou seja, a oposição entre indicativo e subjuntivo se anula e se tem apenas a alternativa no indicativo, independentemente de fatores externos ou de decisão interna de S.

---

<sup>1</sup> «Sobre a modalidade» in A.M. Brito, F. Oliveira, I.P. Lima & R.M. Martelo
(eds.), Sentido que a Vida Faz, Estudos para Óscar Lopes, Porto, Campo das
Letras: 539-545.

Comment: "embora *não sei se vá a Portugal* tenda mais [...]"; na minha experiência é mais do que "tenda": é só usado no sentido no sentido 'não sei se hei de ir'. Não sei se esse uso do conjuntivo não terá caído em desuso no Brasil...

Comment: @Jacinto Não tenho a certeza. Posso dizer _não sei se tenha em casa uma ou duas peças_, mesmo que que seja mais incomum que _tenho_. E embora não seja grande opção (preferiria _vou_ / _irei_) não me parece impossível dizer: _não sei ainda se vá a Portugal; o meu patrão ainda não me disse_.

Comment: Pesquisei `"não" [lema="saber"] "se" ".*"{0,2} [temcagr="PR_SUBJ"]` no cetempúblico e curiosamente uma das entradas é _outro exemplo que gostaria de dar refere-se ao par «não sei se vou» e «não sei se vá» ._

Comment: Pois, eu acho muito estranhos todos esses exemplos com o conjuntivo. Pode ser só coisam minha. No primeiro, sem mais contexto, eu pensaria, será que a pessoa quer dizer "tenho" ou se ainda não decidiu se quer ter um ou ou duas peças.

Comment: @Jacinto OK, eu reconsiderei porque pesquisas em corpus dão sempre a variante com o conjuntivo a significar indecisão do sujeito. Acho que o meu exemplo com "tenha em casa" me soou melhor do que devia porque "tenho em casa" e "tenha em casa" se leem praticamente da mesma maneira.

Answer (score 1):

Complementando a [resposta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/9142/2764) do Artefacto, em pt-BR não encontro um contexto em que "não sei se vá a Portugal" fosse usual, ou sequer compreendido — muitos provavelmente tomariam como erro.

Suspeito que a presença do "se" seja a origem da dúvida; se for o caso, note que o "se", o "que", etc. não pedem necessariamente o subjuntivo, como explicado nessa [resposta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/4141/2764).

Comment: Ainda bem que esclareceste isso; eu já tinha as minhas suspeitas. Não compreendi foi essa de "a presença do 'se' seja a origem da dúvida"... na verdade, este é o único caso que me ocorre em que *se* pode selecionar o presente do subjuntivo.

Comment: @Jacinto Sim, falei do subjuntivo em qualquer tempo — de fato o "se" seria com o pretérito. Levando isso em conta, suponho que o OP esteja familiarizado com o pt-PT.

Comment: Agora fiquei curioso. O mesmo se aplica a expressões como _não sei que te diga_? em pt-BR é preciso dizer qualquer coisa como _não sei o que te devo dizer / hei de dizer_?

Comment: @Artefacto Isso, "não sei o que (te) dizer", ou "não sei o que devo/deveria te dizer".

Answer (score 0):

Após a resposta do @Artefacto, devo acrescentar que minha resposta mostra como são esses tempos verbais em pt-BR.

Presente do Indicativo

Não sei se eu **vou**
Não sei se tu **vais**
Não sei se ele **vai**
Não sei se nós **vamos**
Não sei se vos **ides**
Não sei se eles **vão**

Presente do subjuntivo

Não querem que eu **vá**
Não querem que tu **vás**
Não querem que ele **vá**
Não querem que nós **vamos**
Não querem que vós **vades**
Não querem que eles **vão**

Em pt-BR não existe a forma "não sei se vá".